# Domain of definition for a differntial equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The solution to $y'(x)={x+y(x)\over x}$ is $y(x)=x\cdot ln|x|+cx$.

The textbook states that the Domain of Definition for this function is either $x>0$ or $x<0$ but not $x\neq0$. why?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The domain of definition refers to the domain on which the differential equation itself is defined.

In your example, $y'=\frac{x+y}{x}$ is meaningless if $x=0$, so the domain of definition is $x\ne 0$ or the set $(-\infty,0)\cup (0,\infty)$, which is the same thing.